# Dynamic UITableView embedded in UIView - Calculate Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView embedded into a UIView.  The table view contains an array of dynamic Custom Cells which are a range of heights (as in screenshot below)

Is it possible to calculate and apply the height of the UITable and therefore the parent UIView?

Comment: I must be missing something - Why would you think it wouldn't be possible? (also, no screenshot)

Comment: I think it's not clear enough, do you want to sum up heights of all of the rows and set your parent view's height to it? Otherwise, my simple answer would be enough for you.

Comment: You'll have to calculate the height based on your numbers when you create your table view and set its frame height. just use the the same methods you use to calculate the height of your cells, a good way be to declare a class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGRect parentFrame = {name of your UIView}.frame;
parentFrame.size.height = {name of your UITableView}.frame.size.height;
[{name of your UIView} setFrame:parentFrame];
```

Now you set the height of your parent view to the height of your table view's.

Comment: @Mert How do you do that when using autolayouts?

Comment: you can make setFrame and autolayout work together by using setFrame in layoutSubviews/viewDidLayoutSubviews methods but this is highly fragile and can be buggy with different iOS versions; in short it can only be your last option.